# Regexp for get phone number mask from string

Tags: java, regex, string

i have string with range of phone numbers look like "+7312xxxx - +7657xxxx"(spaces between x and - may be or not be). i need cut this string and get to string with "7312xxxx" and "7657xxxx". i try do it step by step, char by char, but it very stupid and hard and i think i can do this with regexp look like this

```
String somestring="+7312xxxx - +7657xxxx";
String[] array=somestring.split("\someregexppattern");
```

but i dont know how build true regular expression. please tell me how do it.

**EDIT**: thanks for all who help me and give me answers, but know i want know which way is faster? with regular expressions or with splitting by "-"?

Comment: does xxxxx are some numbers?

Comment: yes @Rod_Algonquin they are

Comment: because it would be helpful to design a pattern

Comment: does `-` must be present?

Comment: Wouldn't `String[] array=somestring.split("-");` work, sure it might mean you need to `trim` the result `String`s...

Comment: i need string with "xxxx" because it range for number(yes this maybe some numbers). after that i replace one xxx to 000 and second xxx to 999. for exmaple "7312000" and "76579999" and number "742145683" is exist in this range

Comment: what will be the length @mechanikos

Comment: @MadProgrammer - exactly.. :). There is no need of Regex. Just split based on `"-"` then replace `+` with `""`

Comment: sorry, i`m noob and if use @MadProgrammer solution is better for speed and memory i will use this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
^([^-]*)-(.*)$
```

And the java regex would be,

```
"^([^-]*)-(.*)$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yQ9qP5/6)

First captured group contains all the numbers before `-` and the second captured group contains all the numbers which are after to `-`

To get only the first and second numbers without spaces,

```
String s = "+7312xxxx - +7657xxxx";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([^\\s-]*)\\s*-\\s*(.*)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
      System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

Output:

```
+7312xxxx
+7657xxxx
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/gOXQfz)

Comment: need try it.. it look like solution for my problem

Comment: it just gives 1 match

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee see the ideone link i added.

Comment: it`s useful for me) and how do for get numbers without "+"? i know that i can cut this after splitting but intresting how do it with just one regexp

Comment: oh thanks, but can you answer on my updated question? which way is faster? yours or way by @gkbstar

Answer (score 0):

My regular expression is pretty basic, so there might be a better way, but something like `( )?-( )?`, where the spaces `( )` are optional groups might help, for example...

```
String pattern = "( )?-( )?";
String values = "+7312111111 - +7312222222-+7312333333-+7312444444- +7312555555 -+7312666666";
String parts[] = values.split(pattern);
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Would output...

```
+7312111111
+7312222222
+7312333333
+7312444444
+7312555555
+7312666666
```

You could even use something like `([ ]+)?-([ ]+)?` if the number of spaces are unknown or you could just use `-` and `trim` the result, for example...

```
String values = "+7312111111 - +7312222222-+7312333333-+7312444444- +7312555555 -+7312666666   -   +731277777";
String parts[] = values.split("-");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part.trim());
}
```

**Updated...**

You could use something like `\+7312[0-9]+([ ]+)?-([ ]+)\+7657[0-9]+` to find possible matches...

```
String value = "+7312111111 - +7657222222-+7312333333-+7312444444- +7312555555 -+7312666666   -   +731277777";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+7312[0-9]+([ ]+)?-([ ]+)\\+7657[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
while (m.find()) {
    value = m.group();
}
```

With each matching group, you could just use `value.split("-")` to split the two elements apart as previously demonstrated...

Comment: It`s great! and if exist way to cut number without "+" in one step,show me please

Comment: You mean you want to get just the number without the leading `+`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think you can use \\W+ as the regex in the split method

Comment: but it not work with templates "+7312xxxx - +7657xxxx" just with full numbers

Comment: @mechanikos - use `values =values.replaceAll("\\+","");` . this replaces all your `+`s in the String, then split.

Comment: It will split the string around the `-` marker, it won't care what's between them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to extract:

```
String somestring="+7312xxxx - +7657xxxx";
  somestring=somestring.replaceAll(" ", "");
  String[] array=somestring.split("-");
  for(String s : array)
  {
      System.out.println(s.substring(1));
  }
```

You can store the value to a variable too.

You will get the below output:

```
7312xxxx
7657xxxx
```